# Converting $W/m^2 $ unit

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

In my equation I have a unit measured in MET

[found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_equivalent)

$1MET=58.2 W/m^2 $.
But my other parameter which is metabolic heat generation is measured in  $W/m^3$ .

I want to convert 
$W/m^2$ units to  $W/m^3$. Can someone suggest me a method to do this please?

My original equation is [image: this].

For this I am trying to include the effect from exercise intensity as well. The unit that measures exercise intensity is $W/m^2$.  In my equation the term that actually exists is
$Q_e \over \omega_bp_bc_b$. Units of $Q_m \over \omega_bp_bc_b$ is $m^0C$.
But what I want is to actually have in celcius. $^0C$.
So to get in $^0C$ what sort of adjustment can be done to $Q_e$. Should I use $Q_e $per length or something?

Comment: You cannot, they are completely different units

Comment: @Vishwaas In my equation I have a addition of  parameter measured in both $W/m^2$ and $W/m^3$ . In this case what should I do

Comment: the Wikipedia page doesn't seem to exist for the link you've provided

Comment: @Vishwaas now the link works

Comment: "In my equation I have a addition of parameter measured in both $W/m^2$ and $W/m^3$." The thing to do is to check where you made a mistake in your algebra, or check to see where there is some missing factor multiplying one of those terms. You *cannot* add two quantities that have different units.

Comment: @Vishwaas I edited my post to further explain my problem. Can you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert "watts per meter squared", $\rm W/m^2$, to "watts per meter cubed," $\rm W/m^3$.  Square meters measure area, cubed meters measure volume; they are quite different.

You might as well say, "I have an acre of sod; how tall is it?"  The extra factor of length changes things completely.